# What is the proper way to get someone's attention?

Tags: vocabulario, cortesía

Say I'm walking and I want the attention of someone. What do I say/shout? I'm especially looking for situations where the person is a stranger, but I would like to be polite. In English, you would use *Sir*, *Ma'am*, *Miss*, etc.

What are some ways in Spanish? The ones I've heard are *varón*, *señor*, and *señora*. Are those appropriate words? Are there other better or different ones?

Comment: @Flimzy I have now edited my answer to make it more specific.

Comment: Good improvement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For men I would use *caballero* or *señor* :

> Perdone **caballero**, me permite una pregunta?

or

> Disculpe **señor**, sabe donde esta esta calle?

For women I would use *Señora* or *Señorita*. The first is used to married women, and the second for (younger) unmarried ones. Since yo can't tell, unless they are blatantly old I would go with *Señorita* (middle aged women won't mind to be addressed like *Señorita*, trust me).

If you want to be informal (e.g., your work buddies or friends, in a relaxed environment) you could use *tío* or *colega*.

> **Tío**, me acaba de decir el jefe que nos doblan el sueldo.
>
> Eso no te lo crees ni tú, **colega**.

If you want to go even more informal than that, you could use *tronco*.

> Dame un cigarro **tronco**, que me he dejado el paquete en casa.

Don't use *varón*, because that is Spanish for *male* (And you don't say *"Excuse male, what's the time?*, do you?)

Comment: Tio?  Por que?  "Tio", la hermano de tu padre o madre?  No comprendo.  O otra palabra?

Comment: Sí, la misma palabra. No estoy seguro del origen, pero es como una forma cariñosa de incluir a alguien en la familia (crear familiaridad, como si tus hijos llamasen a tu mejor amigo "Tío Jack" por ejemplo, aunque no sea tu hermano, or similar to call somebody _Bro_ in English). De ahí la forma de emplear la palabra fue evolucionando y ahora con "tío" tienes el significado no solo de "uncle" sino también de "dude", "man" o "bro". Ej: "Eh Tío, mira! No es ese el tío ese que dices que te debe 50 euros? Pídeselos ahora!"

Comment: Perfecta explicacion.  Gracias, Diego!  Y +1.

Comment: Creo que faltan algunas comas, delante de caballero, señor y tronco, como en "Disculpe, caballero". En inglés no se pone coma ahí pero sí en español.

Comment: I disagree with your *señora* / *señorita* recommendation. Nowadays, at least in Spain, *señorita* is considered quite old fashioned or even sexist (you haven't got a specific word for an unmarried men, after all), unless for a very young woman. *Señora* is considered the neutral form, equivalent to *señor*.

Comment: @Gorpik, será que soy de los 80, aunque a mi jamás ninguna mujer me ha recriminado usar "señorita" para dirigirme a ella. Usar "señora" con una chica de menos de 30 es prácticamente **llamarla vieja**. Creo que lo de considerar "señorita" sexista sólo ocurre con gente que intenta llevar la igualdad de sexos demasiado lejos (tipo ["miembros y _miembras_"](http://elpais.com/diario/2009/03/18/internacional/1237330804_850215.html) que dicen a veces los políticos), y tratan de ver cosas donde no las hay, pero llevo 3 años fuera, así que aceptaré tu palabra de que es tendencia ahora en España.

Answer (score 2):

*Oiga* is nice and pretty universal.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Mexico:

If you are talking to an elder man you say:

> Disculpe señor.
>
> Señor.
>
> Oiga, señor.
>
> Señor, disculpe.

Yes, pretty much the same but those are the options.

For an elder woman:

> Disculpe, señora.
>
> Oiga, señora.
>
> Señora.
>
> Señora disculpe.

For some one under fourties, but not a kid:

> Disculpa.
>
> Chavo.
>
> Oye chavo.

And if you are elder than this person that could be a teen:

> Oiga, disculpe joven.
>
> Disculpe.
>
> Joven.
>
> Muchacho.
>
> Niño. (This sounds derogative but can works)

If you are talking to a friend:

> Ey
>
> Oye
>
> Ey güey [Just very close friends and make sure your friend says that word, and just guy-guy or woman-woman, guy-woman most of the tomes is not ok]

Varón can't be used in this case.

Comment: I think you're a little bit wrong. If you find someone under forties, but not a kid is common to use _jóven_ instead of _chavo-. _Chavo_ is more suitable if you're elder that that person and that person is a teen or around 20's. Also, there is young people that with another young people but not close friends use _güey_.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch the attention of some one the more commonly ways are:

> Disculpá (informal)
>
> Disculpame (nethier formal or informal)
>
> Perdon (neither formal or informal)
>
> Discúlpeme (formal)
>
> Disculpe (formal)
>
> Perdoneme (formal)

but if you want to reffer to their gender you can say:

> Chico/a, ... (kids or teenagers)
>
> Joven, ... (young people)
>
> Señor/a, ... (adults)

And also you can mix both like you do in English of course.

The only two that doesn't sound so good if you mix are *Disculpá* and *Disculpame*, but the others you can mix the way you want and the order doesn't matter (also, like in english).

For example, it's almost the same to say *Sir, Excuse me* or *Excuse me, Sir*
and in spanish it's also the same saying *Señor, Disculpe* or *Disculpe Señor*.